# Disabling tab switching with mouse button on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I using Notepad++ with several files and NP++ changes tabs a bit at random. I've figured out that on the laptop I've been given (HP Elitebook) the trackpoint is very sensitive and that tapping it makes NP++ switch tabs.

When I plug in a mouse the same action corresponds to the previous/next buttons. Is there a way to disable this in the NP++ configuration?

Answer (score 1):

---

*Caveats*

- *Unfortunately, this is not a Notepad++ based solution.*
- *This answer likely only applies on Windows and assumes third-party utilities can be installed ([AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)).*
- *There may (theoretically) be hardware limitations that prevent this answer from being a viable option.*

---

> Is there a way to disable this in the NP++ configuration?

Not that I am aware of.

> When I plug in a mouse the same action corresponds to the previous/next buttons.

Assuming that the trackpoint is sending the same keys as the mouse (ex. `XButton1` and `XButton2`), it may be possible to "disable" these buttons while in Notepad++ with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/):

*ex. disable_xbuttons_npp.ahk*

```
; If Notepad++ is open (focused), disable XButton1 and XButton2

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
{
    XButton1:: Return
    XButton2:: Return
}
```

---

**AutoHotkey References**

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Overriding or Disabling Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm)
- [#IfWin[Not]Active / #IfWin[Not]Exist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a HP Elitebook as well and ran into the same problem.
It does appear that this is caused by the Synaptics driver rather than Notepad++

I've fixed it by launching Synaptics Touchpad Settings and in the Synaptics Pointing Device window click disable to deactivate trackpoint acting like a mouse forward button.

Comment: Even more radical for me. I'm not an admin on the machine and this configuration is locked, so I ripped off the rubber on the trackpoint. No more false hits, no more problems :)